# Joining neighbouring x-tics with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

what i want to do is the following: 
I have a number of values that belong to an x-value. like this:

```
A 12
A 13 
A 15 
A 29
B 23 
B 23
B 23
C 90 
C 83
```

so the number of y-values for each x-value differs. What i basically want is a plot that looks like this:

[image: plot i want]

How can i achieve that using numpy and matplotlib? How can i keep matplotlib from repeating the x-value, that is mostly the same anyways? Note that i want 3 y-values plotted, as opposed to only one value showing in the x-axis?

EDIT:
What i currently doing now is simply plotting all pairvalues. looks like this:
[image]

What i need is to replace the repeated values in the x-axis with the value and a blank essentially.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Makes it easier to find the error.

Comment: I don't get your question. You show an example plot, but then state that you want the multiple y-values plotted. Do you mean multiple lines, where the first value of A be connected to the first value of B, etc.? Or do you mean you want to plot dots of all three y-values at the same x? Or is your plot supposed to be an average or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is more like

```
x    y  label
1   12    A
2   13    A
3   15    A
4   29    A
5   23    B
6   23    B
7   23    B
8   90    C
9   83    C
```

and instead of repeating labels, you want a single centered label per group?

```
from itertools import groupby
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    ('A', 12),
    ('A', 13),
    ('A', 15), 
    ('A', 29),
    ('B', 23),
    ('B', 23),
    ('B', 23),
    ('C', 90),
    ('C', 83)
]

labels,ys = zip(*data)
xs = range(len(ys))

def centered(val, ln, empty=''):
    half = (ln - 1) // 2
    return (val if i==half else empty for i in xrange(ln))

def centered_labels(labels):
    return [v for val,grp in groupby(labels) for v in centered(val, len(list(grp)))]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xticklabels(centered_labels(labels))
ax.plot(xs, ys, 'b-', linewidth=3)
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typically in this situation you could plot the **average** value of each group as a single point.

That is, first use numpy to calculate the average of each group (by group I mean A, B, etc), and then plot all of these averages in matplotlib, with one point (the average), for each group.  Beyond this, one could also plot error bars, or a box plot, etc, to give a sense of the distribution within each group, etc.